# Physics in the kitchen: does heat transfer faster from air into oil or from air to food when in an oven?

Tags: thermodynamics, applied-physics, thermal-conduction

It is usually said that foods cook faster in an oven when coated in oil. While I can understand that the underside of the food will cook faster where the oil forms an thermal interface between the food and the metal tray, I am unclear as to how or why the upper surface of the food heats (and so cooks) more rapidly, if indeed it does. Is heat transferred faster from air to cooking oil and to food, or directly from air into food? I was going to assume that food has the thermal properties of water, given most foods are largely water (although I note that muscle/meat [has lower thermal conductivity](https://itis.swiss/virtual-population/tissue-properties/database/thermal-conductivity/) than water). I am also aware that there will be some radiative heating from the oven walls. Water also has a lower boiling point than oil (which would combust before it boils) and I'm struggling to make sense of all the different factors and coefficients and my physics is rather rusty. Would appreciate some sage advice.

Comment: Probably want to think about heat capacities for using oil. Obviously oils can taste better than water too, so there's that not-so-physics consideration also.

Comment: consider that cooking oil has a higher boiling point than water. That means oil on the surface will reach a higher temperature than water on the same surface. A higher temperature on the surface of the food will make it cook faster.

Comment: I suspect that you can only analytically answer this question by knowing the heat transfer coefficients between air-oil, air-food, and oil-food.  These data are probably going to be difficult to acquire, and will vary depending on the oil and the food.  If you can design a well-thought-out experiment, you may have more luck answering this question.